# pyconfig.h fatal error 'io.h' file not found

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt-creator, pyqtdeploy

I've successfully generated a `.pro` file with pyqtdeploy, so I opened the file with Qt Creator.

Android configuration on Qt Creator has no problem, but I get this error `pyconfig.h  fatal error 'io.h' file not found` when I try to build the **apk** (by the way, building exe is no problem).
[image]

**Here are the things I've tried, but didn't work:**

**1.** Added this path to the environment `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt`

**2.** Included the above path in .pro file
[image]

**3.** I found the `io.h` file in my NDK folder, and I tried to included the path in the .pro file `D:\SDK\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\ndk\21.1.6352462\sources\third_party\shaderc\libshaderc_util\include\libshaderc_util`. However, I got crazier errors:
[image]
so, I don't think this is the right way to include `io.h` file.

**4.** I directly copied the `io.h` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt` to the path where `pyconfig.h` is. The error changed, the not found file is no longer `io.h`, but `corect_io.h`.
[image]

And I copied this file and the following not found files from the same path, too. It seemed to work until I met this error:
[image]
The strange thing is `vadefs.h` exhists in the ndk path(shown in error), but it uses `#include_next` trying to find other `vadefs.h`files from other paths. (Am I right?)

I'm totally lost. I don't even know if `No. 4` is the right way to include files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As try number 4 fixed your error, maybe you need to copy the files over to your project until it works. If that works, your include path is probably borked and repairing that depends on the compiler.